# How to allow a gradle plugin to access classes in project dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, classpath, jsonschema

I am writing a gradle plugin to generate a `json-schema` for beans in my project. My goal is to have the schema generated and published as part of the build process so I don't need to keep updating it manually.

Currently, I pass `project.compileJava.inputs.files` to my task and use that to construct a `URLClassLoader`. Then I pass those classes to a [schema generator](https://github.com/mbknor/mbknor-jackson-jsonSchema).

In order to ensure that the json schema is generated correctly, I want to use the `ObjectMapper` from the target application. Unfortunately, my `ObjectMapper` adds the jackson `Hibernate5Module.` In the depths of that module, it tries to check if my class is assignable to a `HibernateProxy,` and since the `HibernateProxy` is loaded with Gradle's class loader and my class is loaded with the `URLClassLoader` everything explodes.

I could remove the Hibernate module, but that still leaves the bug to be triggered in other similar situations, and it makes my plugin less distributable. So I need a way to either add new entries to gradle's classpath or to the default class loader at run time.

For reference, here are the relevent code snippets:

*build.gradle of target project*

```
jsonSchema {
    classpath = project.compileJava.inputs.files
}
```

*public class WriteJsonSchema extends DefaultTask*

```
@TaskAction
public void write() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    mapper.registerModule(new Hibernate5Module());
    mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS, false);
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS, false);

    Set<File> files = getClasspath().getFiles();
    List<URL> urls = new ArrayList<URL>(files.size());
    for(File file : files)
    {
        urls.add(file.toURI().toURL());
    }
    URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls.toArray(new URL[0]), Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());

    JsonSchemaGenerator jsonSchemaGenerator = new JsonSchemaGenerator(mapper);
    JsonNode jsonSchema =
        jsonSchemaGenerator.generateJsonSchema(classLoader.loadClass("com.example.Widget"));
    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonSchema));
    classLoader.close();
}
```

**TL;DR:** I need a way to either add new entries to gradle's classpath or to the default class loader at runtime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If anyone cares, I ended up getting the project classpath by inspecting the outputs of the `compilejava` tasks.

```
classpath = getProject().files();
    getProject()
        .getTasksByName("compileJava", true)
        .forEach(task -> classpath = Classpath.plus(((JavaCompile)task).getClasspath()));
classpath = Classpath.plus(getProject().getTasks().getByName("jar").getOutputs().getFiles());
```